# Arduino FSR reading sketch - analogread' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have written a simple arduino sketch to read the value from a pin using the analogRead(0) function for reading pin 0.

When verifying the code I get the error message -
'analogread' was not declared in this scope.

I have read somewhere that analogRead was superseded by HAL, but I can not find anywhere what should replace analogRead if it is not supported anymore.

Any help/advice would be great and much appreciated.

I have no included libraries in my sketch, maybe this is the reason but I can find an examples that require #include of any library.

The code in my sketch is as follows:

```
int fsrPin = 0; // the FSR and 10K pulldown are connected to a0
int fsrReading; // the analog reading from the FSR resistor divider

void setup(void) {
// We'll send debugging information via the Serial monitor
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
fsrReading = analogRead(0);

Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
Serial.print(fsrReading); // the raw analog reading

// We'll have a few threshholds, qualitatively determined
if (fsrReading < 10) {
Serial.println(" - No pressure");
} else if (fsrReading < 200) {
Serial.println(" - Light touch");
} else if (fsrReading < 500) {
Serial.println(" - Light squeeze");
} else if (fsrReading < 800) {
Serial.println(" - Medium squeeze");
} else {
Serial.println(" - Big squeeze");
}
delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake of mine.

The code is case sensitive and the actual code is analog**R**ead and not analog**r**ead

Comment: I thought so as well, but it's hard to know when your posted code is properly capitalized :)